# fetch, axios not return data timely in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch, axios

In `componentWillMount()` i call `fetch` method to get data. But when `fetch` not loaded. This component was `render`.

How to fix it.? how to fetch loaded before render()

Answer (score 1):

You can't. When you getting data and feeding your component generally you need to check if there is any data. If there is not, either render nothing or render something like "No data." or show a spinner there. Use componentDidMount for that.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: "",
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.setState( {data: json}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.data ? <p>{this.state.data.title}</p>: "No data"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: my `fetch` function does not finish before render. how to fix it

Comment: @VõCátThư like it says in this answer, you "fix it" by making your render function work _before the data is ready_.