# What's the best practice to call API with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I actually face a small problem in React when calling the API, since `ComponentWillMount` is deprecated.

I did this:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();

    this.state = {
      questionsAnswers: [[{ answers: [{ text: '', id: 0 }], title: '', id: 0 }]],

    },
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
   this.getQuestions();
}

getQuestions = async () => {
   let questionsAnswers = await Subscription.getQuestionsAndAnswers();
   questionsAnswers = questionsAnswers.data;
   this.setState({ questionsAnswers });
};
```

So the page is rendered a first time without `questionsAsnwers`, when I get the `questionAnswers` the page is re-rendered

Is there a better solution to avoid a re-render?

Comment: React doc recommends loading it in componentDidMount
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Also https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/302

Comment: in that case keep loading symbol first time and once questions loaded change state which will display questions.. will be getting good user experience as well.. 

Better use redux which gives you better way to handle api call and data binding

Comment: I suggest not using the `async` keyword for any React Component methods because Promises are not cancelable. If the Component is unmounted during the `await`, you will call `this.setState` on an unmounted component. This is why stores like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) were created; React Components are best kept completely synchronous. If you do add async to a Component, create subscriptions inside `componentDidMount` and unsubscribe them in `componentWillUnmount`, but I do suggest avoiding the `async` keyword entirely inside React Component methods.

Comment: If there is no data when your component is rendered first time, then shape your component according to that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697447/fetch-axios-not-return-data-timely-in-reactjs/49697828#49697828

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle API call is in the `componentDidMount` method react lifeCycle according to react documentation. At this moment all you can do is to add a spinner to make your component more user-friendly.
Hopefully, in the next React releases. React will introduce a new way to solve this kind of problem using the `suspense` approach https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-suspense-1c73b4b0b1e6

Answer (score 2):

Using a class with `React.Component` it is `componentDidMount`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {item.name} {item.price}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

If you use a function component with Hooks you should do it like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // Note: the empty deps array [] means
  // this useEffect will run once
  // similar to componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} {item.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Apples",  "price": "$2" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Peaches", "price": "$5" }
  ] 
}
```

Source:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's okay to show spinner in that situation.
And you should also check that ajax did not fail.